# Camera control in power pages

Tags: powerapps

I have a requirement that requires users of my power pages website to take live selfie on my power pages website, the camera should be able detect when the face and ears aren't properly aligned, and also detect when the object taken from the camera is not a human face, power pages doesn't have cameras control. I don't know whether there's any plug-in or AI tool that could be used to achieve this. I will appreciate if anyone could suggest how this can be achieved or implemented.